# Custom title icon in activity

Tags: java, android, icons, custom-titlebar

I need to dynamically set the icon in the title bar. Currently I have this code in my activity:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
setContentView(R.layout.table_layout_activity);
getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.icon_procedure);
```

This works fine, except that it changes the font size and it removes the (default) border line at the bottom of the bar. I'd like to only set the icon and leave everything else as default.

Default title bar:

[image: Default titlebar].

Custom icon:

[image: Custom icon].

Anyone can help?

Comment: Why not use an action bar to set the icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icon can be changed in multiple ways for Activities, programmatically for an individual activity as

In onCreate()

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
// icon is image in res/drawable folder.
```

Or in actionbar theme, by adding this to your ActionBar style.

```
<item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon</item>
<!-- This changes icon universally for all Activities in application -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the action bar, use `setIcon()` on `ActionBar` to change the icon, and get rid of that other stuff.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what you mean by that, though. Do you have an example?

Comment: @user2146129: `ActionBar` is a class. `setIcon()` is a method on that class. If you read [the documentation for `ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html), you will read "From your activity, you can retrieve an instance of ActionBar by calling getActionBar()". This should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Use setIcon() on actionBar() or change it directly in androidManifest.xml